# How to use BigQueryInsertJobOperator to execute a stored procedure in BigQuery, passing parameters to it?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

Through XCOM, I obtain records from a table in BQ using BigQueryGetDataOperator, which I store in a dictionary. My question is, how can I pass this dictionary, key-value pairs as parameters for a stored procedure in BigQuery using BigQueryInsertJobOperator? When I execute without parameters, it works but obviously, I need to pass these (there are several, but I only show one in my code block). I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

```
def get_params_dict(**context):
    table_rows = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='get_data_from_table')
    row_data = {}
    for row in table_rows:
        row_data["p_fecha_ini"] = row[2]
    return row_data

start_sp = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id='start_sp',
        configuration={
            'query': {
                'query': f"CALL `{PROJECT_ID}.{DATASET_ID}.{SP_NAME}`(parameter1)",
                'useLegacySql': False,
            },
        },
        trigger_rule='all_done'
    )
```

I tried something like this, but I got Query error: Query parameter 'p_fecha_ini' not found

```
start_sp = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id='start_sp',
        configuration={
            'query': {
                'query': f"CALL `{PROJECT_ID}.{DATASET_ID}.{SP_NAME}`(@p_fecha_ini)",
                'useLegacySql': False,
                'parameters': [
                    {'name': 'p_fecha_ini', 'parameterType': {'type': 'STRING'}},
                ],
            },
        },
        params=get_params_dict,
        trigger_rule='all_done'
    )
```

Comment: can you check my answer please, and mark it as solved if it helped you to solve your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue, you can create a custom operator that extends `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`.
This technic allows to retrieve easily the value passed by the previous operator via the current context and `XCom`, example :

```py
from typing import Any, Dict

from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator
from google.api_core.retry import Retry
from google.cloud.bigquery import DEFAULT_RETRY

PROJECT_ID = 'project'
DATASET_ID = 'dataset'
SP_NAME = 'sp'


class CustomBigQueryInsertJobOperator(BigQueryInsertJobOperator):

    def __init__(
            self,
            task_id: str,
            configuration: Dict[str, Any] = None,
            project_id: str = None,
            location: str = None,
            job_id: str = None,
            force_rerun: bool = True,
            reattach_states: set[str] = None,
            gcp_conn_id: str = "google_cloud_default",
            impersonation_chain: str = None,
            cancel_on_kill: bool = True,
            result_retry: Retry = DEFAULT_RETRY,
            result_timeout: float = None,
            deferrable: bool = False,
            delegate_to: str = None,
    ) -> None:
        super(BigQueryInsertJobOperator, self) \
            .__init__(
            task_id=task_id,
            configuration=configuration,
            project_id=project_id,
            location=location,
            job_id=job_id,
            force_rerun=force_rerun,
            reattach_states=reattach_states,
            gcp_conn_id=gcp_conn_id,
            impersonation_chain=impersonation_chain,
            cancel_on_kill=cancel_on_kill,
            result_retry=result_retry,
            result_timeout=result_timeout,
            deferrable=deferrable,
            delegate_to=delegate_to)

    def execute(self, context):
        task_instance = context['task_instance']
        table_rows = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_data_from_table')

        row_data = {}
        for row in table_rows:
            row_data["p_fecha_ini"] = row[2]

        # Build the configuration dict from the row data retrieved via the current context and Xcom.
        self.configuration = {
            'query': {
                'query': f"CALL `{PROJECT_ID}.{DATASET_ID}.{SP_NAME}`(@p_fecha_ini)",
                'useLegacySql': False,
                'parameters': [
                    row_data,
                ]
            }
        }

        super(CustomBigQueryInsertJobOperator, self).execute(context)
```

- I created a class `CustomBigQueryInsertJobOperator` that extends `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`
- I overridden the `execute` method
- In the `execute` method, I can retrieve the value passed by the previous operator via the current context and `XCom`
- I can apply your logic and create the query params as `Dict`
- I build the configuration object, set it to the current operator and execute it

Don't hesitate to adapt this code if needed in your side.

Comment: @Marcell Llerena - if you don't want to create a new operator, you can also use a PythonOperator and directly call `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`'s execute method (similar to what @Mazlum is doing).